# Fit image of random size into a ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have a imageview which will contain later some images with random size
I want to fill the imageview with the images but 
keeping the ratio(so don 't use scale type FITXY or centercrop because it trim part of my image)

How can i do this ?

In this test code,I have blank spaces on left and right of my images

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"


     >

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgTest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        android:src="@drawable/test"
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved with a matrix and the height/width of my screen

```
private Bitmap resize(Bitmap bm, int w, int h)
    {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        int newWidth = w;
        int newHeight = h;
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: where can i implement this can you explain a little bit it would be very helpfull,also will this help if h and w is match parent

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/test"/>
```

Comment: some words of clarification would have been nice